# Why did my download speed go down after making these adjustments and what can I do to restore the settings to get speeds back to normal?

Tags: networking, lan

I followed the steps [from a guide](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/window-auto-tuning-in-windows-10) below:

> Use Cortana to search for “CMD.”
> run `cmd`
>
> Right-click on “Command Prompt” and click “Run as administrator.”
> run command
>
> ```
> netsh interface tcp show global
> ```
>
> Look for “Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level” under the results in the
> Command Prompt window.
>
> `auto-tune` If it’s set to enabled, it’s turned on, and may be causing
> your internet issues.
>
> To disable it, run the following command:
>
> ```
> netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
> ```
>
> the results should be immediate, although it is recommended to restart
> your PC and power cycle your network gear just to be safe.
>
> ```
> Successful command entered:
> success
> ```
>
> If that doesn't work for you, you can try to: Press Windows key on
> your keyboard, then type CMD on search, right-click on the result and
> choose Run as Admin. Type these following commands to reset your
> internet/network settings:
>
> ```
> netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
> ipconfig /flushdns
> netsh winsock reset
> Restart your PC and see if the issue is resolved.
> ```
>
> Note, both of these solutions are shots in the dark. You have left us
> with very little information to try and help you with this issue.

I did this to get better download speed on uPlay as before I was getting 4.8/4.9mb. After doing these things it went down to 2.7/2.8mb.

Can I change stuff back or is there like a setting that I can change to get my 4.8/4.9mb download speed?

Comment: Why did you do this in the first place?

Comment: The page you followed these instructions from state this is for older routers; see bold text. Is that your case? Sounds like it isn’t. “Window Auto-Tuning feature is enabled by default in Windows 10 and makes data transfers over networks more efficient. **But if your network uses an old router or your firewall software does not support this feature, then you may experience slow data transfers or even loss of connectivity.**” If you are trying to fine tune your network for speed, you shouldn't just follow random tutorials online like this.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that should have an effect is the auto-tuning. You can set it back to what it was set to before by running

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
```

The other command you ran should simply reset your network stack. Rebooting your PC should clear anything that is left.